# updating a global list python

Tags: python, list, variables, global

Full disclosure -- this is my first stack overflow question. I searched around for a similar question for awhile but couldn't find one that helped me given my limited scope of knowledge (there were python global variable questions but the answers given were over my head).

I'm new to programming and i'm learning python via python the hard way by Zed Shaw. I'm on exercise36 and my goal is to write my own text based game.

The game starts with the following function

```
def start():
global Your_HP
Your_HP = 20
global Your_Ammo
Your_Ammo = 20
global HP_Scan
HP_Scan = 2
global your_stats
your_stats = [Your_HP, Your_Ammo, HP_Scan]

print "You enter a room with two doors"
print "Do you choose the Red Door\n...or the Blue door?"
start_choice = raw_input("> ")

if "red" or "Red" in start_choice:
    monster_HP = 2
    monster_attack = 3

    red_one(your_stats, monster_attack, monster_HP)
```

The red_one function looks like this:

```
def red_one(your_stats, monster_attack, monster_HP):

    print "Immediately you notice a monster in the room"
    print "You point your rifle at the monster before you"


    shoot(Your_Ammo, monster_HP)

    if monster_HP <= 0:
        print "You killed it!"
        print "You now have %d bullets left" % Your_Ammo
        print "You finally look around the room"
        print "There is a door going straight"
        print "There is a door going left"

        room_choose()


    elif monster_HP > 0:
        print "The monster has %d HP" % monster_HP
        print "He stumbles, but not dead!"
        print "He shoots back at you with his lil pistol!"

        get_shot(monster_attack, Your_HP)

    else:
        dead('just because')
```

The script immediately runs the shoot function which looks like:

```
def shoot(Your_Ammo, monster_HP):

    print "---------"
    print "You have %d HP left" % Your_HP
    print "How many shots do you fire?"
    shots_fired = raw_input('> ')
    shots_fired = int(shots_fired)

    Your_Ammo -= shots_fired
    monster_HP -= shots_fired

    return Your_Ammo, monster_HP
```

The problem is that when I run the script and shoot only 1 time, when I return to the start of `red_one`, the `Your_Ammo` and `monster_HP` variables revert to their original values instead of the updated one i'm returning from `shoot`

I've tried moving where I'm declaring the global variables (initially declaring outside of all functions instead of in `start`) and I just get an "x variable is local and global" error.

I know global variables in general are not always the best idea, so I'm just hoping someone can break this down for me in an elegant way and provide a helpful solution, regardless of whether or not it includes a global variable.

Ideally, I'd like to update the variables in the `your_stats` list throughout the course of the game. Essentially, from any function in the game, I want to be able to return any variable within the `your_stats` list so I can use that variable as an argument for other functions until the player runs out of HP or ammo.

Sorry this post was a bit verbose! Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code; it is hard to tell what is in a function and what is not.

Comment: in python, indent is everything,

Comment: `if "red" or "Red" in start_choice:` will always be `True`.

Comment: In `shoot`, you are shadowing the globals with your parameters. Try removing the parameters from `shoot`, then it should use the global variables instead.

Comment: Everything in the boxes are in the functions?

Comment: @tobias_k I want to use the `shoot()` function multiple times throughout the game, passing in different values for `monster_HP` as there are multiple rooms (functions) with different monsters who have different values of `monster_HP`. I'm not sure how I could use `shoot()` interchangeably throughout the game with different rooms/monsters if I were to remove those parameters. Does that make sense? `Your_Ammo` I can declare globally outside of all functions and pull in when needed, but `monster_HP` is dependent on the room's function itself.

Comment: @tobias_k also, what do you mean by `if "red" or "Red" in start_choice:` will always be `True`?

'start_choice' is just whatever string the user passes along in the terminal via `raw_input("> ")`, for instance, they could easily pass in `blue` which would then trigger another function `blue_one` which is a different room with a different monster.

I have left out much of the games code for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @benjamite `if "red" or "Red" in start_choice` will always be True because `"red"` is a truthy value. It doesn't even look at `"Red" in start_choice`. You should have written `if "red" in start_choice or "Red" in start_choice`.

Comment: Don't you want to wait for user input instead of having them just shoot automatically when they walk in the room? And what if it takes more than one shot? Don't you want a loop there? As it is, the most that can happen (`red_one`) is the user shooting once then the monster shooting back.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist good point. how would i be able to loop that if it took more than one shot? right now, if they shoot once and the monster doesnt die, it runs the `get_shot function` which essentially is `Your_HP -= monster_attack` and the script ends. hesitant to use a `while True` loop, but given how much I know at the moment IDK what else I could do to loop there.

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious thing be something like `while monster_HP > 0`? (or whatever you call monster HP)

Comment: @benjamite You are right, making `monster_HP` global won't help. Instead, you should make use of the returned values, i.e. like `Your_Ammo, monster_HP = shoot(Your_Ammo, monster_HP)`. Integers are immutable, i.e. by doing `some_int += something` you do not _change_ that integer but create a new one, thus the number passed in from the outside as a parameter is not affected.